# Рекуррентное решение, комбинаторика

Tags: математика, комбинаторика, дискретная-математика

Кодовое слово может содержать цифры 0, 1..7 , при этом количество числа 0 - нечетное. Сколько вариантов такого слова может быть при длине N? Нужно решить рекуррентно.

Мое решение этой задачи:
Символы кодового слова ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7) и 0, которых должно быть нечетное количество. Получаем a_1=7, конец без нуля = 7_an−1.Следовательно, a_n=7_an-1+8^*n-1 -an*-2. И в результате получаем a_n=6_an-1+8^_n-1.
Но я не понимаю последнего условия задачи, как это можно верно оформить?

Comment: Вообще-то не числа, а цифры...

Comment: `и 0 нечетных` не так же - в первом предложении сказано: нечётное количество нулей. Лучше приведите точную формулировку задания

Comment: @MBo теперь вторая часть содержания должна быть понятней

Comment: ОК, значит, для длины 1 единственный вариант - "0", для длины 2 - 49 вариантов, для длины 3 - 148. Рекуррентное соотношение тут крайне неудобно применять

Comment: @MBo Разве для более длинных вариантов оно не будет удобней? Чем вы воспользовались в ответах выше?

Comment: просто посчитал. Как рекуррентно построить варианты с одним нулем на конце, Получается, мы их строим из невалидных наборов, которые в прошлом счете не участвовали. Может быть, я в этом неправ.

Comment: Для длины 2 неверно написал, 14 вариантов, под формулу вашу эти три длины подходят

Comment: Длина 4: 7*4+343*4=1400 тоже совпадает

Comment: @MBo я не понял из условия, *для длины 1 единственный вариант - "0"*. там же  *может содержать* Его же может и не быть совсем?

Comment: @splash58 для длины 1 - вариант только 0. Условие задачи - нечетное количество, а 0, насколько я помню - четное

Comment: блин, наверное, да

Comment: @MBo У меня на счете ручном все точно также, но в формуле выходит косячно дальше тройки, либо я что-то путаю. Как вы 4-х значное подставили в формулу?)

Comment: Для 5- 12496 тоже совпадает. О чём вопрос - как посчитано для длины 4 или как по вашей формуле посчитать?

Comment: @MBo по моей для этой длины

Answer (score 2):

Ну, если надо рекуррентно, то вот такое решение вас устроит?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

На Python

```
n=5
a=1
for i in range(2,n+1):
    a=6*a + 8**(i-1)
print(a)
```